# Cycles. Image as texture will not render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I am new to cycles and I am running into some trouble.  I am trying to apply an image texture to a plane but it will not show the texture no matter what I do.  I have unwrapped and added a material, then add a wood texture and nothing. I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  I have watched tutorials and they make it work just fine.
By the way, I can make blender internal work just fine.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your node setup, that would help to see where things might be going wrong.

Comment: The easiest way to get an image texture on a plane is using the import images as planes: File->Import->Images_as_Planes it will create a plane with the proper UVs and the image texute applied to the material. Use that and compare it to your existing setup and you'll find what it is that you've been doing wrong

Comment: "It will not show"... what are you seeing instead? Solid black, white, magenta? Like others have stated, more info is needed. Best if you can pack your textures in and [post a .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).